# How to change Excel document type?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created in Excel table macro. Later I removed it. Right now I cannot save properly Excel document as `xlsx` type. I am getting error `the following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks`. How to make it save as *.xlsx*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify an Excel version. For Excel 2010:

`To continue saving as a macro-free workbook, click Yes.`

[[image: Screenshot of save warning]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTQ2G.png)

You may have to use `Save As` instead of `Save`.